# No source code available when attaching to process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, citrix

When I attach to a process, wfica32.exe I get a message saying "no source code available".  This application launches through Citrix.

Of course I have no issues attaching to this application and viewing its source code when it runs locally.  Unfortunetly, the error I experience only occurs when running through Citrix. I suspect a race condition.

I added the `*.pdb` files to the server.  Is it possible to attach to a process and see source code in a Citrix session?

Comment: Wfica32.exe is a Citrix program.  You don't have the source for it, Citrix does.  Treat this like deploying your program on a customer's machine.  Debug locally, fingers crossed after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect to be able to debug an application that runs on a remote computer you are connected with, attaching debugger to Citrix Client process (wfica32.exe you mentioned). What you need to do is to setup remote debugging (which might be just impossible in some cases). You can find more information on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: Ah, is *that* what he was trying to do? In which case it's +1 from me - he needs Remote Debugging. I thought he was using VS on the server, I'd completely missed the clue in wfica32.exe.

Comment: I dont think remote debugger is going to let me debug the citrix process containing my code.

Comment: @Maku- I dont know much about citrix.  I assume that the process citrix runs in somehow launches my program internally in a way I cant touch.  I have access to the server that hosts citrix, but dont know where to go from there.  Install remote debugger then attach to the citrix process?

Comment: Nevermind...trying it out really clarified this for me.  :).  Remote debugger shows my process and I can attach!!!

Answer (score 1):

The PDB files will give you the symbols, but you'll need the source files on the server as well.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean?  I need to copy the project solution onto the server?  I'm not sure how this will help.  FWIW, I do have the source files on my local machine.

Comment: The easiest thing is to debug under VS, then you can step through the source as well, although you could also use WinDBG. How are you debugging it presently?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 - tagged in question.  That is what I am currently doing.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - You need to supply Visual Studio with the source. The fact it works on your local machine proves this.  There are products on the market that allow you to debug a library you don't have the source to, they do this, by decompiling the library in question of course.

Comment: OK, so copy the project files across, yes. I'm surprised if you were using VS it didn't ask you (with a file open dialog) to tell it where the source files for the code you're debugging is. It won't help you with wfica32.exe though if it's not your program. The best you'll get is symbols with assembly for that.

Comment: FYI, remote debugger was successful by doing a debug build.  There's no need to copy *.proj/*sln files...

Comment: No, you only need the source files wherever you're running Visual Studio. I thought at first you were running it on the server, but with remote debugging you run it all on the client.